# Anonymous response during service consumption iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ios8, afnetworking

I am facing anonymous behavior of service response. Sometime service fetched well and sometimes it gives an error message **"A server with specified host name can't be found"**. I am using `AFNetworking`. Same service worked very well in android platform. Is there any better way to fetch them accurately in iPhone.

here is my piece of code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

                NSDictionary *params = @{@"email"     : txtEmail.text,
                                         @"password"    : txtPassword.text,

                                        };
                AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
                operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
                [operationManager POST:@"http://somelink/someuser.svc/login" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", operation.responseString);
                    NSDictionary *responseDict = responseObject;
                    NSLog(@"%@",[responseDict valueForKey:@"result_code"]);
                    if ([[responseDict valueForKey:@"result_code"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                        NSDictionary *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result_data"];
                        NSLog(@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"email"]);


                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[data objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"UserId"];
                        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into userMaster (user_id, name_first, name_last, email, password, image, gender, rec_limit, total_followers, total_following, is_brand, category) values ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@',%d,'%@','%@',%d,%d)",[data objectForKey:@"user_id"],[data objectForKey:@"name_first"],[data objectForKey:@"name_last"],[data objectForKey:@"email"],[data objectForKey:@"password"],[data objectForKey:@"image"],[data objectForKey:@"gender"],[[data objectForKey:@"rec_limit"]intValue],[data objectForKey:@"total_followers"],[data objectForKey:@"total_following"],[[data objectForKey:@"is_brand"]intValue],[[data objectForKey:@"category"]intValue]];

                        //                    NSLog(@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"intrests"]);


                        NSLog(@"%@",query);
                        int n = [service insertUpdateDeleteWithQuery:query inDatabase:@"WaveDb.sql"];
                        NSLog(@"%d",n);

                        NSArray *arr = [data objectForKey:@"intrests"];
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
                            NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]);

                            query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into userCategory (user_id, cat_id) values ('%@','%@')",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"UserId"],[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
                            [service insertUpdateDeleteWithQuery:query inDatabase:[DataClass databaseName]];
                        }



                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]hideProgress];
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"login"];
                            WallViewController *main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wallView"];
                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]hideProgress];
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Invalid username and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert show];
                    }
                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]hideProgress];
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Some technical error occured. Try later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert show];

                    });
                }];



            });
```

Comment: It seems to be error `NSURLErrorCannotFindHost (Error nb 1003). Could be a DNS Issue, there are some similar question on SO. Try maybe with IP instead of web address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `reachability` before any code execution is solved my problem.